# Accumulating errors with EitherT

Tags: haskell, error-handling, either

I have the following little mini-sample application of a web API that takes a huge JSON document and is supposed to parse it in pieces and report error messages for each of the pieces.

Following code is a working example of that using EitherT (and the errors package). However, the **problem** is that EitherT breaks the computation on the first Left encountered and just returns the first "error" it sees. What I would like is a list of error messages, all that are possible to produce. For instance, if the first line in `runEitherT` fails then there's nothing more that can be done. But if the second line fails then we can still try to run subsequent lines because they have no data dependency on the second line. So we could theoretically produce *more* (not necessarily all) error messages in one go.

Is it possible to run all the computations lazily and return all the error messages we can find out?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (pack)
import Web.Scotty as S
import Network.Wai.Middleware.RequestLogger
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Types
import Control.Lens hiding ((.=), (??))
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Control.Error
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as H
import Network.HTTP.Types

data TypeOne = TypeOne T.Text TypeTwo TypeThree
  deriving (Show)

data TypeTwo = TypeTwo Double
  deriving (Show)

data TypeThree = TypeThree Double
  deriving (Show)

main :: IO ()
main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware logStdoutDev

  post "/pdor" $ do
    api_key <- param "api_key"
    input   <- param "input"

    typeOne <- runEitherT $ do
      result       <- (decode (pack input) :: Maybe Value) ?? "Could not parse. Input JSON document is malformed"
      typeTwoObj   <- (result ^? key "typeTwo")            ?? "Could not find key typeTwo in JSON document."
      typeThreeObj <- (result ^? key "typeThree")          ?? "Could not find key typeThree in JSON document."
      name         <- (result ^? key "name" . _String)     ?? "Could not find key name in JSON document."
      typeTwo      <- hoistEither $ prependLeft "Error when parsing TypeTwo: " $ parseEither jsonTypeTwo typeTwoObj
      typeThree    <- hoistEither $ prependLeft "Error when parsing TypeThree: " $ parseEither jsonTypeThree typeThreeObj

      return $ TypeOne name typeTwo typeThree

    case typeOne of
      Left errorMsg -> do
        _ <- status badRequest400
        S.json $ object ["error" .= errorMsg]
      Right _ ->
        -- do something with the parsed Haskell type
        S.json $ object ["api_key" .= (api_key :: String), "message" .= ("success" :: String)]

prependLeft :: String -> Either String a -> Either String a
prependLeft msg (Left s) = Left (msg ++ s)
prependLeft _ x = x

jsonTypeTwo :: Value -> Parser TypeTwo
jsonTypeTwo (Object v) = TypeTwo <$> v .: "val"
jsonTypeTwo _ = fail $ "no data present for TypeTwo"

jsonTypeThree :: Value -> Parser TypeThree
jsonTypeThree (Object v) = TypeThree <$> v .: "val"
jsonTypeThree _ = fail $ "no data present for TypeThree"
```

Also open to refactoring suggestions if anyone has some.

Comment: Error-accumulating `ErrorT` can't be made a proper `Monad`. Only `Applicative`. So you need a different type (like [`These`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.3/docs/Data-These.html) only in a transformer form) or a `newtype` wrapper with different `Applicative` instance.

Comment: A `TheseT` transformer would definitely be the way to go!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you have at least 2 ways of accumulating error. Below I elaborate on those. We'll need these imports:

```hs
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Monoid
import Data.These
```

### `TheseT` monad transformer

*Disclaimer:* `TheseT` is called [`ChronicleT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these-0.4.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Chronicle.html#t%3aChronicleT) in [`these` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these).

Take a look at the definition of [`These` data type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/these/docs/Data-These.html#t%3aThese):

```
data These a b = This a | That b | These a b
```

Here `This` and `That` correspond to `Left` and `Right` of `Either` data type. `These` data constructor is what enables accumulating capability for `Monad` instance: it contains both result (of type `b`) and a collection of previous errors (collection of type `a`).

Taking advantage of already existing definition of `These` data type we can easily create `ErrorT`-like monad transformer:

```
newtype TheseT e m a = TheseT {
  runTheseT :: m (These e a)
}
```

`TheseT` is an instance of `Monad` in the following way:

```
instance Functor m => Functor (TheseT e m) where
  fmap f (TheseT m) = TheseT (fmap (fmap f) m)

instance (Monoid e, Applicative m) => Applicative (TheseT e m) where
  pure x = TheseT (pure (pure x))
  TheseT f <*> TheseT x = TheseT (liftA2 (<*>) f x)

instance (Monoid e, Monad m) => Monad (TheseT e m) where
  return x = TheseT (return (return x))
  m >>= f = TheseT $ do
    t <- runTheseT m
    case t of
      This  e   -> return (This e)
      That    x -> runTheseT (f x)
      These _ x -> do
        t' <- runTheseT (f x)
        return (t >> t')  -- this is where errors get concatenated
```

### `Applicative` accumulating `ErrorT`

*Disclaimer:* this approach is somewhat easier to adapt since you already work in `m (Either e a)` newtype wrapper, but it works only in `Applicative` setting.

If the actual code only uses `Applicative` interface we can get away with `ErrorT` changing its `Applicative` instance.

Let's start with a non-transformer version:

```
data Accum e a = ALeft e | ARight a

instance Functor (Accum e) where
  fmap f (ARight x) = ARight (f x)
  fmap _ (ALeft e)  = ALeft e

instance Monoid e => Applicative (Accum e) where
  pure = ARight
  ARight f <*> ARight x = ARight (f x)
  ALeft e  <*> ALeft e' = ALeft (e <> e')
  ALeft e  <*> _        = ALeft e
  _        <*> ALeft e  = ALeft e
```

Note that when defining `<*>` we **know** if both sides are `ALeft`s and thus can perform `<>`. If we try to define corresponding `Monad` instance we fail:

```
instance Monoid e => Monad (Accum e) where
  return = ARight
  ALeft e >>= f = -- we can't apply f
```

So the only `Monad` instance we might have is that of `Either`. But then `ap` is not the same as `<*>`:

```
Left a <*>  Left b  ≡  Left (a <> b)
Left a `ap` Left b  ≡  Left a
```

So we only can use `Accum` as `Applicative`.

Now we can define `Applicative` transformer based on `Accum`:

```
newtype AccErrorT e m a = AccErrorT {
  runAccErrorT :: m (Accum e a)
}

instance (Functor m) => Functor (AccErrorT e m) where
  fmap f (AccErrorT m) = AccErrorT (fmap (fmap f) m)

instance (Monoid e, Applicative m) => Applicative (AccErrorT e m) where
  pure x = AccErrorT (pure (pure x))
  AccErrorT f <*> AccErrorT x = AccErrorT (liftA2 (<*>) f x)
```

Note that `AccErrorT e m` is essentially `Compose m (Accum e)`.

---

**EDIT:**

`AccError` is known as [`AccValidation`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation/docs/Data-Validation.html#t%3aAccValidation) in [`validation` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation).

Comment: Thank you for the implementation of the types! I had already refactored my code to use `These` based on the earlier comment so just adding your instances for `TheseT` helped to bring it in line with the previous implementation a bit more.

Adding a few helper functions makes it look quite similar to the EitherT code, but now it accumulates code as expected.

Of course, the real trick to making all of this work is to provide sensible "default/empty" data from which the program can continue computation should an error be encountered.

Code: https://gist.github.com/ique/be2af7f274597a55945a

Comment: @Fredrik if `TheseT` suits you, perhaps you should just use `ChronicleT` from `these` package (as mentioned in answer). That is instead of home-grown `TheseT` transformer.

Answer (score 0):

We could actually code this as an *arrow* (Kleisli transformer).

```
newtype EitherAT x m a b = EitherAT { runEitherAT :: a -> m (Either x b) }

instance Monad m => Category EitherAT x m where
  id = EitherAT $ return . Right
  EitherAT a . EitherAT b
       = EitherAT $ \x -> do
              ax <- a x
              case ax of Right y -> b y
                         Left e  -> return $ Left e

instance (Monad m, Semigroup x) => Arrow EitherAT x m where
  arr f = EitherAT $ return . Right . f
  EitherAT a *** EitherAT b = EitherAT $ \(x,y) -> do
      ax <- a x
      by <- b y
      return $ case (ax,by) of
        (Right x',Right y') -> Right (x',y')
        (Left e  , Left f ) -> Left $ e <> f
        (Left e  , _      ) -> Left e
        (  _     , Left f ) ->        Left f
  first = (***id)
```

Only, that would violate the arrow laws (you can't rewrite `a *** b` to `first a >>> second b` without losing `a`'s error information). But if you basically see all the `Left`s as merely a debugging device, you might argue it's okay.